# Two divs one with text content and other one with just image how can i keep both the div with same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

These are Two `div's` with one `div` having text and another one with only image in it.

[image]

When I Change even the slightest of the viewport the `div` image gets small and the div with text in it increases I want both the `div` to remain of same height without using media query and Flex is there any option using javascript??

[image]

```html
<div class="book cf">
          <div class="book-content">
            <span class="title">world ocean summit 2017</span>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Delectus aspernatur similique, aperiam suscipit autem 
               doloribus quos accusantium,
            </p>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Read More">
              read more
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Book Now">
              book now
            </a>
            <div class="location">
              <span class="icons">
                  <i class="fa fa-map-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="text">
                bali, indonesia
              </span>
              <span class="icons">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="text">
                  february 22nd-24th 2017
              </span>  
            </div>     
          </div>
          <div class="book-image">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/643x389" alt="Man" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

```css
.book-content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #5eabd7;
  text-align: center;
}

.book-content .title {
  padding-top: 60px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.book-content p {
  padding: 7% 8%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.book-content a {
  padding: 2% 6%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.book-content p+a { background-color: #ffffff; }

a[title^="Book"] { background-color: #ffe401; }

.book-image {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.book-image img {  width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Please post the **relevant** code and markup you have issue with instead of links to images, preferably in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem. See [**Why not to upload Images of Code when asking a Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Define a css class to style the width, height, padding, borders and margins. Make sure this class will be good for the image. Apply the class to both divs. If need be, you can create another class without width, height etc. and apply such class to any of the div that may require it. Note it will be better if both divs are children of same parent (e.g. body).
Note however that if the text is associated with the image, then use the html picture tag. Wrap the text and image inside a p tag The p is a child of the picture. This is better for UX.
Browsers will always resize as the screen size changes. In this case, you will also need css to handle media screen size changes (responsive). e.g.

```
<source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
<source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
<img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
```

You can read more about this here: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp'

Answer (score 0):

Just find image height on page loading, then assign its result to the left div, then both divs looks with same height. Its a trick may be this help you. try this

Comment: No I cant assign height to div its not allowed